# Saving Nunit generated XML result using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation, nunit

I have an Automation framework with Selenium using C#.
I am using NUnit for running,testing, and saving Xml result which is generated by NUnit itself.

Now my Question : How we can save this XML result using automation itself ?

Comment: Anything you've tried?

Comment: I have searched but couldnt find anything productive..